# VueJs CLI 3 - how add external lib

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

I have a vue app created by latest [vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/) (vue 3.5.1) using this following command line:

> vue ui

This is my folder structure:

app_vue:
|- node_modules
|- public
|- src:
|---- assets
|---- components:
|---------**List.vue**
|---- libs:
|--------- **pagination**:
|------------- css:
|----------------- **pagination.css**
|------------- js:
|----------------- **pagination.js**
| ...

The **libs** folder doesn't exist before I just created manually.

I also create manully **vue.config.js** file but I don't know what I should add here.

```
const path = require('path')
module.exports = {}
```

My List.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
     ...
     <div id="pagination"></div> 
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  // how use pagination.js ???
  export default {
   ...
  }
</script>
<style>
  //how use pagination.css ???
  ...
<..style>
```

I want use the **pagination** libs in **List.vue** component.
I want to use something like that:

> libs/pagination/pagination.css

not

> ../../libs/pagination/pagination.css

How I can do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the files in just your components/views, you import what you want into the files that need them: import MyLib from "../path/to/libs"; is an example.

However, if you want something to be added globally, you can do add them in your `App.vue` (or your base Vue component), in a non-scoped style tag:

```
<style>
@import "https://cdn.materialdesignicons.com/2.5.94/css/materialdesignicons.min.css";
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons";

#app {
  font-family: "Hilda-Regular", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
</style>
```

The example above will expose all the styles to your entire application. If you put any styles in a [scoped](https://css-tricks.com/saving-the-day-with-scoped-css/) style tag, they will be scoped to that component or view.

Comment: That's not how you import JS: [MDN Import JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: sorry I wanted say import  '@/libs/pagination/js/pagination.js' using folder alias

Comment: Ah, yes you can do that! @ is an alias to the src directory I think

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import this library and it is ES6 or other module then you might want to use [chainWebpack](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#chainwebpack) option and define something like

```
 module.exports = (api, options) => {
   api.chainWebpack(webpackConfig => {
     webpackConfig.resolve
      .alias
      .set('~', api.resolve('lib'))
   }
}
```

For more example you might want to look [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/ff57b8f55fa69873f643e418cfe6d4842d7c7674/packages/%40vue/cli-service/lib/config/base.js#L49-L50)

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works  for me.

**vue.config.js**

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config.resolve.alias
            .set('libs', path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/libs/'))
    }
}
```

**List.vue**

```
<script>
   import { Pagination } from "libs/pagination/js/Pagination.js"
   import 'libs/pagination/css/pagination.css'

   export default {
       ...
       mounted()
       {
           console.log(new Pagination("#pagination"))
       }
       ...
   }
</script>
```